# CrystalReports : change TextObject with embedded field at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

With CrystalReports it is possible to change the text of TextObjects at runtime like this :

```
var ro = (TextObject)report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Text24"];
to.Text = "New text";
```

but if the TextObject contains embedded field, it is not working. For exemple with the code bellow :

```
ro.Text = "Duty-free price : {?Price}";
```

The TextObject will render like the text property "Duty-free price : {?Price}" without evaluating the field... In fact, the field expression become a part of the text.

Is there an other property/method witch preserve embedded expressions ?

Comment: Try like this "Duty-free price :"& {?Price}

Comment: This looks like a Crystal Report expression but I need to do this in C#